# Expo save calendar events

Tags: android, calendar, expo

I'm trying to save a calendar event in and Expo app on Android. Here's some code:

```
const details = {
  endDate: "2018-05-16T20:00:00.000Z",
  location: "...",
  notes: "...",
  startDate: "2018-05-16T19:00:00.000Z",
  timeZone: "GMT-7",
  title: "...",
  url: "http://www..."
};

try {
  console.log('Adding Event');

  const eventId = await Calendar.createEventAsync(Calendar.DEFAULT, details);

  console.log("Event Id", id);
}
catch(error) {
  console.log('Error', error);
}
```

In this case, "Adding Event" is logged. But then nothing. No event id or error. And the event doesn't show up in my calendar.

This is running through the Expo app on Android.

The calendar item is saved perfectly on iOS.

I ask for calendar permissions up front, so I don't think that's the problem.

What could be going wrong here? How do I debug this?

Comment: couldn´t you create a breakpoint via `debugger;` and open the dev tools in the emulator, then step forward? that´s how i would try to debug it

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documents the functionality to get the default calendar is only available on ios devices:

> Calendar.getDefaultCalendarAsync() iOS only. Gets an instance of the
>   default calendar object.
>   https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/calendar/#calendargetdefaultcalendarasync

on Android you could iterate through the results of getCalendarsAsync until you find the one with isPrimary: true. like so:

```
const calendars = await Calendar.getCalendarsAsync();
const calendar = calendars.find(({isPrimary})=>isPrimary);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to do this directly from native app but became such a complicated task for something simple.

If someone wants a simple & quick solution just create an iCS (generic calendar format) file and upload It to some kind of direct file download cloud (I used firebase) and when the user wants to add to calendar just send him to the ICS calendar link download.

Answer (score 0):

When attempting this myself (early 2020) on Android, I came up with all internal calendars in my devices having isPrimary: false.

With Android, you can first create an independent calendar which your app will update(which will be reflected on the device calendar apps). To avoid bloating your device with calendars every time you attempt to save a new event, you can first search to see if your calendar already exists in the device. You can then either add to that one, or create a new one (initial run)

```
var defaultCal //the calendar ID you are passing to createEventAsync()

if( Platform.OS == 'ios' ) {
  defaultCal = getDefaultCalendarId()
} else {
  defaultCal = getAndroidCal()
}


async function getAndroidCal() {
  var androidCalendar
  var foundCal = false
  // retrieve internal calendars
  var androidCalendars = await Calendar.getCalendarsAsync();
  // iterate through them
  for( var x=0; x<androidCalendars.length; x++ ) {
    // check each to see if their source name matches what you have
    if ( androidCalendars[x]["source"]["name"] == "*your identifier*" ) {
      foundCal = true
      // save the calendar id and stop searching
      androidCalendar = androidCalendars[x]["id"]
      break
    } 
  }
  // initial run
  if( foundCal === false ) {
    androidCalendar = await createCalendar()
  }
  return androidCalendar
}


//  create a calendar for android 
async function createCalendar() {
    const newCalendarSource = { 
        isLocalAccount: true, 
        name: '*your identifier*' 
      }

     const newCalendarID = await Calendar.createCalendarAsync({
       title: *your title*,
       color: *your color*,
       entityType: Calendar.EntityTypes.EVENT,
       sourceId: newCalendarSource.id,
       source: newCalendarSource,
       name: *calendar name*,
       ownerAccount: 'personal',
       accessLevel: Calendar.CalendarAccessLevel.OWNER,
     });

      return newCalendarID
    }
```

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score -2):

try creating the event in this way.

`var eventi= await Expo.Calendar.createEventAsync(Expo.Calendar.DEFAULT,{
      startDate: new Date('2018-09-14'),
      endDate: new Date('2018-12-31'),
      title: "push",
      timeZone: "GMT-7",
      alarms: 
    })
    .then( event => {
      console.log('success',event);
        })
  .catch( error => {
      console.log('failure',error);
      });`

I also faced some issues while passing the event as a const but resoved them while  doing it this way.
I am not sure what caused the error.

Comment: Ask for permission first...

_askForCalendarPermissions = async () => {
    const response = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CALENDAR);
    const granted = response.status === "granted";
    return granted;
  };